# shell script to create folder daily with time-stamp and push time-stamp generated logs

Tags: bash, shell, unix, cron, aix

I have a cron job which runs every 30 minutes to generate log files with time-stamp like this:

```
test20130215100531.log, 
test20130215102031.log
```

I would like to create one folder daily with date time-stamp and push log files in to respective date folder when generated.

I need to achieve this on AIX server with bash.

Comment: What about a cronjob that creates the directory at 00.00 every night? And then modify actual cronjob to push files to this directory.

Comment: I would recommend `mkdir -p` for creating missing directory each time without complaining if it already exists. What if 00:00 job fails to run for some reason (system being down), do we want all daily jobs to fail because of it?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I prefer your option.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am not going to configure the above requirement in the cronjob. I have a shell script which creates log files. i need to write some script to have the directory and push generated logs in to that

Comment: OK. What did you code so far?

Comment: Why don't you write the log files in the right directory in the first place instead of "pushing" them in afterwards with another script?

Comment: yeah.. i need to the same.. creating a directory just once when the day starts and write logs for the same day in to the directory.. Right now, i am forming the logs through a script and placing in one location with timestamp.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob  # This line is so that it does not complain when no logfiles are found
for filename in test*.log; do # Files considered are the ones starting with test and ending in .log
    foldername=$(echo "$filename" | awk '{print (substr($0, 5, 8));}'); # The foldername is characters 5 to 13 from the filename (if they exist)
    mkdir -p "$foldername"  # -p so that we don't get "folder exists" warning
    mv "$filename" "$foldername"
    echo "$filename $foldername" ;
done
```

I only tested with your sample, so do a proper testing before using in a directory that contains important stuff.

*Edit in response to comments:*

Change your original script to this:

```
foldername=$(date +%Y%m%d)
mkdir -p  /home/app/logs/"$foldername"
sh sample.sh > /home/app/logs/"$foldername"/test$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).log
```

Or if the directory is created somewhere else, just do this:

```
sh sample.sh > /home/app/logs/$(date +%Y%m%d)/test$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).log
```

Comment: Thanks so much !! How would that be if i can create a directory just once when the day starts and write logs for the same day in to the directory. Right now.. i am forming the logs through a script placing in one location with timestamp.

Comment: Could you post the part of your script that creates the log file with the timestamp? It is easier to work from that. _(If you edit your question, also leave a comment here, so I get notified)_

Comment: // am doing some configuration stuffs here then executing another script to create the file as below.
sh sample.sh > /home/app/logs/test$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).log

The above runs every 30 minutes, which would generate 48 logs in a day

Comment: Read my edit. This creates a folder name YYYY/MM/DD (if it does not exist), and stores the data there.

Comment: thanks so much ! Hope the files for one date will not get misplaced with the above solution..

Comment: I guess there is a small chance (in the last script) that the date changes between the two `date` calls, but I would think it is a bit slim. But do some test first, anyway

Comment: Hi @user000001. This one worked for me:  
mkdir -p  /home/app/logs/$(date +%Y%m%d)
But when i assign date to a variable 'foldername', its not creating any folder:
mkdir -p  /home/app/logs/"$foldername"
Even i tried by removing double quotes, but no success.
However in my another bash script, i am using variable the same way (witout double quotes) and it works fine.
Any idea whats wrong ??

Comment: 1. As for the quotes, it is better to use them, otherwise the script will fail if the variable has spaces in it. See also _[word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting)_. 2. One reason for the above command not to work would be if you have spaces before or after the `=`. Do an `echo "$foldername"` to see if it gets assigned. You can also do a quick check of the script at http://www.whatswrongwithmyscript.com/.

Comment: folder_name="$(date +%Y%m%d)"  
echo "$folder_name"
This itself doesnt print any output and there is nothing wrong shown in whatwrongwithmyscript URL.

Comment: :-) This too didn't work. Anyways Thanks for all your help. Let me investigate more on this.

Comment: Well if `echo "THIS SHOULD BE PRINTED"; folder_name="$(date +%Y%m%d)"; echo "$folder_name"` does not print either then you know the problem is somewhere else...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24716/discussion-between-user1746666-and-user000001)

Comment: I was executing all this before EOF.. (ssh node <<EOF) It had some problems i believe.. 
Now i am executing after EOF.. It works great.. 
Thank you for all your help and time..

Comment: Ok that explains it... No problem

Answer (score 2):

You should use logrotate! It can do this for you already, and you can just write to the same log file.

Check their man pages for info:
http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html