# Create folders automatically and move files

Tags: linux, bash, move

I have a lot of daily files that are sort by hours which comes from a data-logger (waveform). I downloaded inside a USB stick, now I need to save them inside folders named with the first 8 characters of waveform.

Those files have the following pattern:

> Year-Month-Day-hourMinute-##.Code_Station_location_Channel

for example, inside the USB I have:

2020-10-01-0000-03.AM_REDDE_00_EHE; 2020-10-01-0100-03.AM_REDDE_00_EHE; 2020-10-02-0300-03.AM_REDDE_00_EHE; 2020-10-20-0000-03.AM_REDDE_00_EHE; 2020-10-20-0100-03.AM_REDDE_00_EHE; 2020-11-15-2000-03.AM_REDDE_00_EHE; 2020-11-15-2100-03.AM_REDDE_00_EHE; 2020-11-19-0400-03.AM_REDDE_00_EHE; 2020-11-19-0900-03.AM_REDDE_00_EHE;

I modified a little a code from @user3360767 ([shell script to create folder daily with time-stamp and push time-stamp generated logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894605/shell-script-to-create-folder-daily-with-time-stamp-and-push-time-stamp-generate)) to speed up the procedure of creating a folder and moving the files to them

```
for filename in 2020-10-01*EHE; do  
    foldername=$(echo "$filename" | awk '{print (201001)}');
    mkdir -p "$foldername"  
    mv "$filename" "$foldername"
    echo "$filename $foldername" ;
done
```

> 2020-10-01*EHE

Here I list all hours from  2020-10-01-0000-03.AM_REDDE_00_EHE

> foldername=$(echo "$filename" | awk '{print (201001)}');

Here I create the folder that belongs to 2020-10-01 and with the following lines create the folder and then move all files to created folder.

```
    mkdir -p "$foldername"  
    mv "$filename" "$foldername"
    echo "$filename $foldername" ;
```

As you may notice, I will always need to modify the line `for filename in 2020-10-01*EHE` each time the file changes the date.
Is there a way to try to create folders with the first 8 number of the file?

Tonino

Comment: Your question is quite hard to follow... it just launches into a load of stuff that doesn't work. Maybe you could click `edit` underneath it and update it by starting with what you actually do want to achieve. You want to move some files automatically each morning/night/week/month? The files are created by another program? They need to be moved (or copied?) to a new folder based just on the date (or the date and time?) in their filename (or depending on the system date?)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `date`

And since the `foldername` doesn't change, you don't need to keep creating one inside the loop.

```
files="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)*EHE"
foldername=$(date +%Y%m%d)
mkdir -p "$foldername"
for filename in $files; do  
    mv "$filename" "$foldername"
    echo "$filename $foldername" 
done
```

Edit:

If you want to specify the folder each time, you can pass it as an argument and use `sed` to get the filename pattern

```
foldername=$1
files=$(echo $1 | sed 's/\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)/\1-\2-\3/')
filepattern="$files*EHE"
mkdir -p "$foldername"
for filename in $filepattern; do
  mv "$filename" "$foldername"
  echo "$filename $foldername"
done
```

You call it with

```
./<yourscriptname>.sh 20101001
```

Comment: the variable   `files="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)*EHE"` does not list all files it only shows 2020-10-01.*EHE and then it can not move any file to folder, by the way the folder name will change for each day

Comment: @tonino I don't understand. `files` isn't listing all the files that match the pattern? It uses `date` so the pattern for today will be 2020-12-03*EHE or 2020-12-02*EHE depending on your timezone.

Comment: I did a bad explication, the files are waveform that comes from a data-logger, this equipment saves information each hour in the format mentioned, I downloaded the data from past months. The main idea is to move the files to a folder named with the 8 first characters (20201001), this is the tricky part I am not able to manage

Comment: @tonino If I understood correctly, you will have to pass it as an argument to the script, check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to move all files whose names end in `*EHE` into subdirectories. The subdirectories will be created as necessary and will be named according to the date at the start of each filename without the dashes/hyphens.

Please test the following **on a copy** of your files in a temporary directory somewhere.

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in *EHE ; do
    # Derive folder by deleting all dashes from filename, then taking first 8 characters
    folder=${filename//-/}
    folder=${folder:0:8}
    echo "Would move $filename to $folder"
    # Uncomment next 2 lines to actually move file
    # mkdir -p "$folder"
    # mv "$filename" "$folder"
done
```

**Sample Output**

```
Would move 2020-10-01-0000-03.AM_REDDE_00_EHE to 20201001
Would move 2020-10-01-0100-03.AM_REDDE_00_EHE to 20201001
```

Note that the 2 lines:

```
folder=${filename//-/}
folder=${folder:0:8}
```

use *"bash parameter substitution"*, which is described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) if you want to learn about it, and obviate the need to create whole new processes to run `awk`, `sed` or `cut` to extract the fields.

Comment: works fine and very useful the bash parameter substitution